# how to know if a reactive form is being edited on angular2

Tags: angular

In my angular2 app i have a reactive form like:

```html
   <form [formGroup]="personForm" novalidate>
      <input class="form-control" 
        [ngClass]="{'edited':personForm.value}" // this line*
        formControlName="name">
      <label>Name</label>
      //here i have more other inputs like this one
   </form>
```

This form is used in two situations, when im creating a new person and when im editing a existent person. So i would like to know how to change the 'edited' property when im editing or creating a new person. The 'personForm.value' is always true, so it desnt work.

Comment: How is the form supposed to know that? You need to set that in whatever's *using* the form.

Answer (score 0):

`personForm.value` is a json object which contains all fields and corresponding values of the `formGroup`
The form can't know if you are editing an existing person or creating a new one, you need to use a component variable and check for editing yourself. (for example, checking for an id variable in your route params)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.

In the class corresponding to your form

```
.
.
.
export class MyForm ... {
  isEditing = false;

  onFocus() {
    this.isEditing = true;
  }
  onBlur() {
    this.isEditing = false;
  }
}
```

Then modify your template like so

```
<form [formGroup]="personForm" novalidate>
    <input class="form-control" (focus)='onFocus()' (blur)='onBlur()'
        [ngClass]="{'edited':isEditing}" // this line*
        formControlName="name">
     <label>Name</label>
      //here i have more other inputs like this one
</form>
```